# "32 - Could not authenticate you." error in tweepy

Tags: python, django, twitter, tweepy

I was working with tweepy with Django and the code was working fine.

But, when I deployed the code on railway (similar to Heroku), the app showed these logs:

```
File "/app/tweet_scrapper/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "/app/tweets/apps.py", line 10, in ready
from . import jobs
File "/app/tweets/jobs.py", line 85, in <module>
scrap()
File "/app/tweets/jobs.py", line 69, in scrap
searched_tweets = api.search_tweets(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 33, in wrapper
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1309, in search_tweets
return self.request(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 263, in request
raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
32 - Could not authenticate you.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
worker.init_process()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
self.callable = self.load()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
return self.load_wsgiapp()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
__import__(module)
File "/app/tweet_scrapper/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "/app/tweets/apps.py", line 10, in ready
from . import jobs
File "/app/tweets/jobs.py", line 85, in <module>
scrap()
File "/app/tweets/jobs.py", line 69, in scrap
searched_tweets = api.search_tweets(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 33, in wrapper
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1309, in search_tweets
return self.request(
File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 263, in request
raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
32 - Could not authenticate you.
```

It was working fine locally.

I have elevated access to Twitter API.

I checked all the keys and tokens, and they're correct (but I'm accessing them from environment variables).

My authentication code is this:

```
secret_key = os.environ.get('secret_key')

secret_key_api = os.environ.get('secret_key_api')

access_token = os.environ.get('acess_token')

access_token_api = os.environ.get('access_token_api')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(secret_key, secret_key_api)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_api)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

In case, it is caused by requirements.txt, here are the things I included:

```
Django==4.0.5
django-environ==0.9.0
asgiref==3.4.1
pytz==2022.5
schedule==1.1.0
tweepy==4.11.0
tzdata==2022.1
urllib3==1.26.9
gunicorn==19.0.0
whitenoise==6.0.0
```

Comment: "I checked all the keys and tokens, and they're correct"—that's the most likely cause. Are you _entirely_ sure? You've inspected the variables after loading from the environment? Are you aware that you've misspelled one of the environment variables? `access_token = os.environ.get('acess_token')` is missing a `c`.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause of it. Thanks!